# Form failing to save one attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, foreign-keys

I have a form that is saving all but one attribute. :user_id (a foreign key) persists in coming out as nil. This is a form for creating a new comment, and it's located in my impressions#show file, so that may be part of the problem; but the other attributes (:name and :impression_id) seem to be saving fine.

Here's the form:

```
= form_for @comment do |f|
   = f.label 'Add Comment'
   %br
   = f.text_area :body, placeholder: 'Comment', cols: 50, rows: 3
   %br
   = f.hidden_field :impression_id, :value => @impression.id
   = f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id
   %br
   = f.submit "Save"
```

The relevant section of the impressions_controller is:

```
 def show
   @impression = Impression.find(params[:id])
   @play = Play.find_by(id: @impression.production.play_id)
   @production = Production.find_by(id: @impression.production_id)
   @comments = Comment.where(impression_id: @impression.id)
   @comment = Comment.new
 end
```

In the comments_controller, I have the following:

```
def new
  @impression = Impression.find(params[:impression_id])
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  authorize @comment
end

def create
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  authorize @comment
  if @comment.save
    flash[:notice] = 'You have successfully added a comment.'
    redirect_to :back
  else
    flash[:notice] = 'Please try again.'
    render :new
  end
end

private

def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :impression_id, :user_id)
end
```

As you can see, I'm trying to assign :user_id the value of current_user.id, but it isn't taking. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

I've tried adding comment_params to my impressions controller, but I get an error message that the param comment is empty . . .

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First check **current_user** if the value of current_user is coming fine  then it has to save user_id in your comments table.

Comment: My current_user has a value and an id . . . it's just not saving to :user_id for the new comment!

Answer (score 0):

If your user is not logged in, current_user is nil.
Make sure that your user is logged in

Comment: My user is logged in, and has an id.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question...

Maybe your hidden field is not sending `user_id` inside the comments subhash. Check your params and see. Your comment_params method expects it to be inside the comments subhash.

And how do you check these params?

Either look at your rails console after each form submission, or
if you are using rails 4.2, check https://gorails.com/episodes/rails-4-2-introduction about 4 minutes in...,

or...

in your gemfile, put

```
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
end
```

bundle (in your terminal), restart your rails server

and then in your controller code, at a line where current_user SHOULD exist, type the line `raise "oops"`, run the code, get an error, then go to http://localhost:3000/__better_errors to see your console

This will give you an error page with a console, in which you can type out any variable name (params, current_user, whatever) and check its value.

Comment: This all sounds wonderful! Unfortunately, I'm getting a runtime error for the line "raise," which I put in my comments controller, and I don't see an error page or a console. Where would they be?

Comment: you should have a brand new pretty error page, but only IF you install better_errors and binding_of_caller, and only IF you are in development. THen you have to bundle and restart the rails server. I'll get this to happen then send you a screenshot. Stand by.

Comment: yes, I did all that, but *where* is this new error page? Is it supposed to replace the current error page I keep getting in Preview?

Comment: I amended my instructions. Check out the new url

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately, I still get a runtime error if I put "raise" in my controllers, so for now this solution doesn't seem to work for me. Anyhow, I've determined that my current_user is logged in, and does have a user_id; it's simply not feeding into comment.user_id for some reason. I can't figure it out!

Comment: Check my edited answer again. My theory is at the top. Can screenshare if you need to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69413/discussion-between-dwilbank-and-ellen-w).